# failed to start the database services MSSQL$Sharepoint

Tags: error, installation, sql-server

I am trying to install Share Point 2010 Foundation on a Win7 SP1 64-bit desktop.

It installed with an error, something about Office components.

When I start the SharePoint Central Admin Web App, I receive:

> Cannot browse to SharePoint Admin Web
>   App because a SharePoint Admin Web App
>   has not been created yet.  To create
>   one, use the SharePoint Products
>   Config Wizard.  Do you want to launch
>   the config wizard now?

I choose Yes, and then receive:

> Failed to start the database services
>   MSSQL$Sharepoint. Repair this product
>   by selecting it from the Add/Remove
>   Programs menu.

I have the following services:

- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) (running)
- SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) (not running)
- SQL Server Browser (not running)
- SQL Server VSS Writer (not running)

What do I need to do from here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect during your installation, the SQL Server Express Install Failed.

Rerun the SQL Server Express Installer and create a Instance called SHAREPOINT

After that, go to Start > Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products > SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard and run through the wizard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Where do I find the SQL Server Express Installer?

Comment: Hi Steve. It should be somewhere in the Sharepoint install folder. Otherwise just download it and install it : http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded and installed it, and opened SQL Server Configuration Manager, but there is no option to create an instance called SHAREPOINT.

Comment: No comment ? ? ? ? ?

Comment: Hi Steve. My apologies mate. I haven't been online in a while. So you've downloaded SQL Management Studio. Firstly, open "SQL Server Configuration Manager" . click on the "SQL Server Services" Tab.. Are you able to see a SQL Instance called SHAREPOINT?? It will be in brackets. Something like SQL Server(SHAREPOINT)... If it's not there, you'll have to create a new instance. Use the SQL Server Installation Center (64-bit) and add a new Instance called SHAREPOINT. If it does exist, you shouldn't have any problems installing. Make sure the instance is started and run the setup.Let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Fox! I really appreciate it! Apparently, all the solutions to this error are available only for Sharepoint 2007! Once again thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to regedit.exe, browse `HKLM_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Shared Tools/Web Server Extensions/14.0/WSS/`. Then change the value of attribute named `ServerRole` from `SINGLESERVER` to `APPLICATION`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to regedit.exe, browse `HKLM_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Shared Tools/Web Server Extensions/14.0/WSS/`. Then change the value of attribute named ServerRole from **SINGLESERVER** to **APPLICATION**.
But in windows 8.1 please watch

```
HKLM_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Shared Tools/Web Server Extensions/**14.0**/WSS/
```